# How to convert Java program to Python

Tags: java, python

I am looking to convert an old Java program with many classes to a python equivelent program for my company. Since I am not many years into either langauge (pretty new) I was wondering if you had any pointers to get me started on my simplest class.

***Currently I am getting stuck on one segment where the old line 3 is defining a variable within a variable and python does not agree with it.***

In this class all that is happening is the OG creator is defining variables to pull a source and destination folder for our in company automated file transfers. I will include the code I have converted so far below and include updates!

The Orignal Java Code is:
'''
public class Driver {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GetSrcAndDest gsad = new GetSrcAndDest();
    System.out.println("Source folder: " + gsad.getSource());
    System.out.println("Destination folder: " + gsad.getDestination());

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    GetDropFolder gdf = new GetDropFolder(gsad.getSource(), gsad.getDestination());'''
```

So far my conversion looks like this:

```
class Driver:
gsad = GetSrcAndDest() #Creating Get Source & Dest variable
print("Source Folder: " + gsad.getSource()) #Printing the Source Folder
print("Destination folder: " + gsad.getDestination()) #Printing Destination Folder

gdf = GetDropFolder(gsad.getSource(), gsad.getDestination()) #Defining Drop folder from Source folder and Destination folder
```

Comment: Hello! At the moment, your question isn't really answerable. Can you identify any specific snippets of Java that you are having trouble idiomatically replicating in Python? As a side note, you really shouldn't place procedural code in the definition of a Python class. Your best course of action would likely be [learning Python](https://www.python.org/doc/) and then replicating features rather than trying to make a line-by-line copy of the two programs.

Comment: Hey Brian, I was having trouble inputing my more updated code snip but figured it out. As I put in bold in the revision, I am unsure the best way to convert the old line 3 (GetSrcAndDest gsad = new GetSrcAndDest();) into python. Any advice on other visual blocks would be much appriciated as well :)

Comment: @Monkey55--in the Java version you have the method `main` with the variables local to main.  Why come you don't have a similar structure in Python but instead have all variables as class variables?

Comment: What part of converting `GetSrcAndDest gsad = new GetSrcAndDest()` is confusing? The part where you have to implement `GetSrcAndDst` in Python or the variable assignment?

Comment: @DarrylG Your saying to centralize my classes into one solid Method? I can definitely get behind that, but I need to research more into this . Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @hmm I am just not sure how the conversion would look from Java to Python. Since posting this, I have changed things alittle playing around. Where I am getting caught is some how getting that function defined at the same time as the variable. I am stumped

Comment: @Monkey55--whoa, no I wasn't saying that.  I was only suggesting following the form of the Java Class which has a method (main) and instance variables inside the method.

Comment: @DarrylG Oh my bad I read that fast. I agree and have since created a primary method for this class.

Comment: @Monkey55--seems you Java class is missing a couple of closing brackets and you should have `public class Driver {` as code.  I only mention it since someone may miss this as being a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-write code to another language, you have to do it from scratch. Programming languages are implementations of the logic a program. When you say line 3, are you referring to this line? `System.out.println("Source folder: " + gsad.getSource());` If so, what is the error? Do you have any error message you can share? Note that you have to define a `GetSrcAndDest` class in your python code, you cannot just use a java class in a python program.

Comment: Yea I am more looking to use the Java script as a guide for the new one since they are both following the same logic.
I am referencing the Java line '''GetSrcAndDest gsad = new GetSrcAndDest();
In this line it looks like a variable is defining a function, right? I am not sure how that would look in Python....

Comment: No, it is not defining a function. In java, we create a new instance of a class by calling its constructor. For example, supposed you have a class named Person. You can do the following, `Person myFriend  = new Person()`. Which languages have you used in the past?